# How to print out each digit of a number by place values in ascending order

Tags: c

i need to create scanf function that accepts random positive integer and using while loop print out each digit of the inputted integer in separate lines, starting from its rightmost digit until the leftmost digit of the number.

input sample: 214

out put sample:
4
1
2

this is my code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main(){
    int num;
    int i;
    
    scanf("%d",&num);

    for(i=0; num>i; i++){

        if(num>=i){
        i = i%10;
        printf("%d", i);
        }
        
    }

return 0;
}
```

edit:
i finally got the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
int num;
int reminder;
int rev=0;
int count=1;

scanf("%d", &num);



while(num!=0)
{
    
    reminder=num%10;
    rev=rev*10+reminder;
    num/=10;

    printf("%d\n",(reminder%10));
  
    count++; 
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah but how can i print it in ascending order?

Comment: Put the digits into an array or list and then sort that. If you don't know how to sort then do some research - there are countless posts and fully worked examples on how to sort.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep on dividing the number by 10 to discard the last digit once you have printed it out using `%` operator.

For loop could look like:

```
for(i=num; i>0; i/=10)
{
    print("%d",(i%10));
}
```